# Why My Service dont restart and show an error (attached)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, timer

In Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP the function to start a Windows Service in Automatic(Delayed) mode isn´t available, so I need make that simulation with code, but when I start the service this will show a message that I need wait cuz are a Timer in the code and this need finish to start. But now I get this error "Tghe PcRegister Service service on local Computer started and then stopped. Some Services stop automatically if they have no work to do, for example, the Performance Logs and Alerts service"... Please I need help to add the timer.

```
class WinService : System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase`
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new WinService() };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }


    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PcRegisterService();
    }


    protected override void OnStop()
    {

    }


    public void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.ServiceName = "WinService";
        RestartService("WinService", 600000);
    }


    public static void RestartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
    {
        ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);

        try
        {
            int millisec1 = Environment.TickCount;
            TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

            service.Stop();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);

            // count the rest of the timeout
            int millisec2 = Environment.TickCount;
            timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds - (millisec2 - millisec1));

            service.Start();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
        }

        catch
        {
            // ...
        }

    }


    public static void PcRegisterService()
    {
    }


    public static class PerformanceInfo
    {
        [DllImport("psapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool GetPerformanceInfo([Out] out PerformanceInformation PerformanceInformation, [In] int Size);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct PerformanceInformation
        {
            public int Size;
            public IntPtr CommitTotal;
            public IntPtr CommitLimit;
            public IntPtr CommitPeak;
            public IntPtr PhysicalTotal;
            public IntPtr PhysicalAvailable;
            public IntPtr SystemCache;
            public IntPtr KernelTotal;
            public IntPtr KernelPaged;
            public IntPtr KernelNonPaged;
            public IntPtr PageSize;
            public int HandlesCount;
            public int ProcessCount;
            public int ThreadCount;
        }

        public static Int64 GetTotalMemoryInMiB()
        {
            PerformanceInformation pi = new PerformanceInformation();
            if (GetPerformanceInfo(out pi, Marshal.SizeOf(pi)))
            {
                return Convert.ToInt64((pi.PhysicalTotal.ToInt64() * pi.PageSize.ToInt64() / 1048576));
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because - I would say - something in your RestartServicve method you blow (with an exception). THe code makes no sense. As in none at all. THere is no need to restart a service at all. THis is now how services work. Back to reading the documentation.

Comment: Im sorry, Im new in the world of programmation, In the work all tolds me that Google are my best friend... the code in the service are so long it´s that the reason that I dont include it... I need that the service wait to start at the final cuz make a network connection with another server, so if dont are a network connection the info cant be send

Comment: THe world is full of people withuit knowledge. Forget google. READ THE DOCUMENTATION, learn the langauge. Get a good book or two. DO not look for single item solutions, learn the fundamentals.

Comment: what book do you recommend??

Comment: C# for dummies to start (the whole dummies series is very well done) followed by the whole relevant .nET documentation front to end.